# BASH: How to write values generated by a for loop to a file quickly

Tags: bash, io

I have a for loop in bash that writes values to a file. However, because there are a lot of values, the process takes a long time, which I think can be saved by improving the code.

```
nk=1152
nb=24

for k in $(seq 0 $((nk-1))); do
    for i in $(seq 0 $((nb-1))); do
        for j in $(seq 0 $((nb-1))); do
            echo -e "$k\t$i\t$j" 
        done
    done
done > file.dat
```

I've moved the output action to after the entire loop is done rather than `echo -e "$k\t$i\t$j" >> file.dat` to avoid opening and closing the file many times. However, the speed the script writes to the file is still rather slow, ~ 10kbps.

Is there a better way to improve the IO?

Many thanks
Jacek

Comment: Define "long time". This is a triple loop, so it'll take nk x nb x nb iterations to complete, or about 663,552 rounds. That doesn't seem like a ton so long as you're not running this all the time.

Comment: @tadman Yes it's not that long per se, but using 3 to 4 minutes to write 6MB of data does not feel ideal to me. I don't mind the IO speed right now since I won't run the script that many times, but just out of curiosity and self-improvement, is there a better way to output the data?

Comment: `seq` is an external utility from the shell. The `$( )` creates a subshell that gives more overhead than it should be. Using a POSIX compliant shell there are builtins to do what you're after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `seq` calls are fairly punishing since that is a separate process. Try this just using shell math instead:

```
for ((k=0;k<=$nk-1;k++)); do
    for ((i=0;i<=$nb-1;i++)); do
        for ((j=0;j<=$nb-1;j++)); do
            echo -e "$k\t$i\t$j" 
        done
    done
done > file.dat
```

It takes just 7.5s on my machine.

Another way is to compute the sequences just once and use them repeatedly, saving a lot of shell calls:

```
    nk=1152
    nb=24

    kseq=$(seq 0 $((nk-1)))
    bseq=$(seq 0 $((nb-1)))

    for k in $kseq; do
        for i in $bseq; do
            for j in $bseq; do
                echo -e "$k\t$i\t$j" 
            done
        done
    done > file.dat
```

This is not really "better" than the first option, but it shows how much of the time is spent spinning up instances of `seq` versus actually getting stuff done.

Bash isn't always the best for this. Consider this Ruby equivalent which runs in 0.5s:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

nk=1152
nb=24

nk.times do |k|
  nb.times do |i|
    nb.times do |j|
      puts "%d\t%d\t%d" % [ k, i, j ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Use `<=` instead of `<` in the bash math to generate the same output.

Comment: Good answer. Process creation is almost always a killer in bash.

Comment: the `$` is not needed inside the `(( ))` but it does not hurt to use also.

Comment: @paxdiablo Having a terminal program that shows what process(es) are being executed helps a lot here. The title was flashing repeatedly with each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

What is the most time consuming is calling `seq` in a nested loop. Keep in mind that each time you call `seq` it loads command from disk, fork a process to run it, capture the output, and store the whole output sequence into memory.

Instead of calling `seq` you could use an arithmetic loop:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i nk=1152
declare -i nb=24
declare -i i j k

for ((k=0; k<nk; k++)); do
  for (( i=0; i<nb; i++)); do
    for (( j=0; j<nb; j++)); do
      printf '%d\t%d\t%d\n' "$k" "$i" "$j"
    done
  done
done > file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `seq` in a subshell consumes most of the time.

Switch to a different language that provides all the needed features without shelling out. For example, in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $nk = 1152;
my $nb = 24;

for my $k (0 .. $nk - 1) {
    for my $i (0 .. $nb - 1) {
        for my $j (0 .. $nb - 1) {
            say "$k\t$i\t$j" 
        }
    }
}
```

The original bash solution runs for 22 seconds, the Perl one finishes in 0.1 seconds. The output is identical.

Comment: Bash *is* a real programming language. If you're going to insult it, you may as well insult Perl as well, and write your code in C :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I know bash and use it a lot. Without real variables (bash variables are in fact just macros) it's far from what I call a programming language. I didn't mean to insult it.

Answer (score 0):

@Jacek : I don't think the I/O is the problem, but the number of child processes spawned. I would store the result of the `seq 0 $((nb-1))` into an array and loop over the array, i.e.

```
nb_seq=( $(seq 0 $((nb-1)) )
...
  for i in "${nb_seq[@]}"; do
    for j in "${nb_seq[@]}"; do
```

Answer (score 0):

`seq` is bad) once i've done this function special for this case:

```
$ que () { printf -v _N %$1s; _N=(${_N// / 1}); printf "${!_N[*]}"; }
$ que 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And you can try to write first all to a var and then whole var into a file:

```
store+="$k\t$i\t$j\n"
printf "$store" > file
```

No. it's even worse like that)